# Dual-WAN Traffic

Tags: networking, router, lan, wan

I am setting up a Cisco RV320 Dual-WAN router.  I am trying to set it up so that that a particular LAN device (i.e. IP Address 192.168.1.9) will only use WAN port 2.  I have found the page in the configuration page to set this up, but is the LAN device the source or the destination?  I have included a link to a screenshot of the setup page.  Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCOVC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LAN device would be the "**Source IP**" or `192.168.1.9` in both fields.

> *Source IP and Destination IP—Internal source and the external destination
>   for the traffic that goes through this WAN port. For a range of IP addresses,
>   enter the first address in the first field and the final address in the To field.
>   For a single IP address, enter the same address in both fields.* - [Page 57 of the Cisco RV320/RV325 Administration Guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/routers/csbr/rv320/administration/guide/en/rv32x_ag_en.pdf)